How can I pass multiple parameters to a community toolkit maui popup in a view model?
I'm trying to display a popup y closmessage  box that will automatically close. But what I would like to do is send that message box two parameters. The first is a string  that is the actual message. The second is an optional string for the header. So far I have the popup XAML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ctm:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:ctm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
           xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:LockAndKeyMaui.ViewModels"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LockAndKeyMaui.MsgBox"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False"
           Color="Blue">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Success!"
            Margin="5,5,0,0" FontSize="20"
            FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="Arial"
            TextColor="White" x:Name="lblHdr"/>
        <Label 
            Text="Completed Successfully..."
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            FontSize="16" FontFamily="Arial"
            TextColor="Yellow" x:Name="lblMsg"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ctm:Popup>

And then I have the view model for the Message Box:
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LockAndKeyMaui.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MsgViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string? msgtxt, hdrtxt;

        public string MsgTxt
        {
            get => msgtxt!;
            set
            {
                msgtxt = value;
                OnPropChg(nameof(MsgTxt));
            }
        }

        public string HdrTxt
        {
            get => hdrtxt!;
            set
            {
                hdrtxt = value;
                OnPropChg(nameof(HdrTxt));
            }
        }

        private readonly IPopupService popupService;

        public MsgViewModel(IPopupService popupService)
        {
            this.popupService = popupService;
        }


        public void DisplayPopup(string ptxt, string? phdr = null)
        {
            this.popupService.ShowPopup<MsgViewModel>(onPresenting: vwMod => vwMod.PerformUpdts(ptxt, phdr!));
        }

        public void PerformUpdts(string txt, string hdr)
        {
            HdrTxt = hdr;
            MsgTxt = txt;
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropChg(string prName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prName));
        }
    }
}

The code-behind for the popup is:
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;

namespace LockAndKeyMaui;

public partial class MsgBox : Popup
{
    public MsgBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

I then Try to display the popup from another view model like this:
popupService.ShowPopup<MsgViewModel>(onPresenting: vwMod => vwMod.PerformUpdts("User Name copied.", ""));
                Task.Delay(1500);
                popupService.ClosePopup();
                return;

And the popupService.ShowPopup command throw the error:

'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

So can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to fix this?
